# Clichouse visitParamExtract - extract second value by key in case with duplicated keys

Tags: clickhouse

visitParamExtractString is extract value by key. If key is not uniq. Function just return first match. What a possbile ways to get second match or third match ?

From docs :
Fields are searched for on any nesting level, indiscriminately. If there are multiple matching fields, the first occurrence is used

```
SELECT time, visitParamExtractSting(message, 'interval') as interval
FROM stage.logs dl 
WHERE time >= '2022-09-29 23:00:00'
order by time
```

raw looks like :

```
{"body":[{"value":3,"interval":"SECOND","intervalNum":10},{"value":205015,"interval":"DAY","intervalNum":1}],"code":200,"endpoint":"/api/v3/rateLimit/order"}
```

in this case i want get "interval":"DAY"  instead "interval":"SECOND"
so result shoult be like :

```
time                      interval
2022-10-30 20:02:01.333   DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

visitParam is a simple function and a very fast function because of that it's not possible.

You have to use JSONExtract* functions. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/#jsonextractjson-indices_or_keys-return_type

```
SELECT tupleElement(JSONExtract('{"body":[{"value":3,"interval":"SECOND","intervalNum":10},{"value":205015,"interval":"DAY","intervalNum":1}],"code":200,"endpoint":"/api/v3/rateLimit/order"}', 'body', 'Array(Tuple(value Int64, interval String, intervalNum Int64))'), 'interval') AS j

┌─j────────────────┐
│ ['SECOND','DAY'] │
└──────────────────┘
```